# Is there a faster way of computing the product of two cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say I want to compute the cycle that is equivalent to $(421)(432)$.

The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is by first finding the permutation associated with $(432)$ and $(421)$, finding the product of these permutations to get a 'new permutation', and then finding the cycle that corresponds to this 'new permutation'.

However, this seems rather laborious to me. Is there a faster way of finding the single cycle that is equivalent to the product of two cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at $(432)(421)$ we see that $1\to 4 \to 3$, $3 \to 2$, $2 \to 1$; i.e. $(432)(421) = (132)$. I'm not sure if this is what you are after (or if this is actually what you described in your question.)

Comment: So you started with 1, then followed it to 4 by the right cycle. But how does 4 then lead to 3? It appears that you've jumped to the other cycle but why did you use that one and not map the 4 to the 2, as per the right cycle?

Comment: By convention of cycle multiplication you act once with each cycle, from right to left.